# Bison's analysis Pascal grammar in C

Tags: c, grammar, pascal, bison

I am writing program to analyse Pascal grammar. I want to check correctness of input Pascal file and show where errors are.

I have a problem with finding more than one error, after finding an error parser ends.

Also parser doesnt't show in which line error is only display " Syntax error at or before [declaration], line" but i want to this line where is an error.

I used : http://ccia.ei.uvigo.es/docencia/PL/doc/bison/pascal/

pascal.l

```
%{
/*
 * pascal.l
 *
 * lex input file for pascal scanner
 *
 * extensions: to ways to spell "external" and "->" ok for "^".
 */

#include <stdio.h>
#include "pascal.tab.h"
int line_no = 1;

%}

A       [aA]
B       [bB]
C       [cC]
D       [dD]
E       [eE]
F       [fF]
G       [gG]
H       [hH]
I       [iI]
J       [jJ]
K       [kK]
L       [lL]
M       [mM]
N       [nN]
O       [oO]
P       [pP]
Q       [qQ]
R       [rR]
S       [sS]
T       [tT]
U       [uU]
V       [vV]
W       [wW]
X       [xX]
Y       [yY]
Z       [zZ]
NQUOTE  [^']

%%

{A}{N}{D}                          return(AND);
{A}{R}{R}{A}{Y}                    return(ARRAY);
{C}{A}{S}{E}                       return(CASE);
{C}{O}{N}{S}{T}                    return(CONST);
{D}{I}{V}                          return(DIV);
{D}{O}                             return(DO);
{D}{O}{W}{N}{T}{O}                 return(DOWNTO);
{E}{L}{S}{E}                       return(ELSE);
{E}{N}{D}                          return(END);
{E}{X}{T}{E}{R}{N}        |
{E}{X}{T}{E}{R}{N}{A}{L}           return(EXTERNAL);
{F}{O}{R}                          return(FOR);
{F}{O}{R}{W}{A}{R}{D}              return(FORWARD);
{F}{U}{N}{C}{T}{I}{O}{N}           return(FUNCTION);
{G}{O}{T}{O}                       return(GOTO);
{I}{F}                             return(IF);
{I}{N}                             return(IN);
{L}{A}{B}{E}{L}                    return(LABEL);
{M}{O}{D}                          return(MOD);
{N}{I}{L}                          return(NIL);
{N}{O}{T}                          return(NOT);
{O}{F}                             return(OF);
{O}{R}                             return(OR);
{O}{T}{H}{E}{R}{W}{I}{S}{E}        return(OTHERWISE);
{P}{A}{C}{K}{E}{D}                 return(PACKED);
{B}{E}{G}{I}{N}                    return(PBEGIN);
{F}{I}{L}{E}                       return(PFILE);
{P}{R}{O}{C}{E}{D}{U}{R}{E}        return(PROCEDURE);
{P}{R}{O}{G}{R}{A}{M}              return(PROGRAM);
{R}{E}{C}{O}{R}{D}                 return(RECORD);
{R}{E}{P}{E}{A}{T}                 return(REPEAT);
{S}{E}{T}                          return(SET);
{T}{H}{E}{N}                       return(THEN);
{T}{O}                             return(TO);
{T}{Y}{P}{E}                       return(TYPE);
{U}{N}{T}{I}{L}                    return(UNTIL);
{V}{A}{R}                          return(VAR);
{W}{H}{I}{L}{E}                    return(WHILE);
{W}{I}{T}{H}                       return(WITH);
[a-zA-Z]([a-zA-Z0-9\-])*           return(IDENTIFIER);

":="                               return(ASSIGNMENT);
'({NQUOTE}|'')+'                   return(CHARACTER_STRING);
":"                                return(COLON);
","                                return(COMMA);
[0-9]+                             return(DIGSEQ);
"."                                return(DOT);
".."                               return(DOTDOT);
"="                                return(EQUAL);
">="                               return(GE);
">"                                return(GT);
"["                                return(LBRAC);
"<="                               return(LE);
"("                                return(LPAREN);
"<"                                return(LT);
"-"                                return(MINUS);
"<>"                               return(NOTEQUAL);
"+"                                return(PLUS);
"]"                                return(RBRAC);
[0-9]+"."[0-9]+                    return(REALNUMBER);
")"                                return(RPAREN);
";"                                return(SEMICOLON);
"/"                                return(SLASH);
"*"                                return(STAR);
"**"                               return(STARSTAR);
"->"                        |
"^"                                return(UPARROW);

"(*"                        |
"{"                                { register int c;
                                    while ((c = input()))
                                    {
                                      if (c == '}')
                                        break;
                                      else if (c == '*')
                                      {
                                        if ((c = input()) == ')')
                                          break;
                                        else
                                          unput (c);
                                      }          
                                      else if (c == '\n')
                                        line_no++;
                                      else if (c == 0)
                                        commenteof();
                                    }
                                }

[\t\f " "]                            ;

\n                                line_no++;

.                                { fprintf (stderr,
                                    "'%c' (0%o): illegal character at line %d\n",
                                    yytext[0], yytext[0], line_no);
                                }

%%

commenteof()
{
  fprintf (stderr, "Unexpected EOF inside comment at line %d\n", line_no);
  exit (1);
}

yywrap ()
{
  return (1);
}
```

pascal.y

```
%{
/*
* pascal.y
*
* Pascal grammar in Yacc format, based originally on BNF given
* in "Standard Pascal -- User Reference Manual", by Doug Cooper.
* This in turn is the BNF given by the ANSI and ISO Pascal standards,
* and so, is PUBLIC DOMAIN. The grammar is for ISO Level 0 Pascal.
* The grammar has been massaged somewhat to make it LALR, and added
* the following extensions.
*
* constant expressions
* otherwise statement in a case
* productions to correctly match else's with if's
* beginnings of a separate compilation facility
*/

#include<stdio.h>

%}

%token AND ARRAY ASSIGNMENT CASE CHARACTER_STRING
%token COLON COMMA CONST DIGSEQ DIV DO DOT DOTDOT
%token DOWNTO ELSE END EQUAL EXTERNAL FOR FORWARD
%token FUNCTION GE GOTO GT IDENTIFIER IF IN LABEL LBRAC
%token LE LPAREN LT MINUS MOD NIL NOT NOTEQUAL OF OR
%token OTHERWISE PACKED PBEGIN PFILE PLUS PROCEDURE
%token PROGRAM RBRAC REALNUMBER RECORD REPEAT RPAREN
%token SEMICOLON SET SLASH STAR STARSTAR THEN
%token TO TYPE UNTIL UPARROW VAR WHILE WITH

%%
file    : program
        | module
        ;

program : program_heading semicolon block DOT
        ;

program_heading : PROGRAM identifier
        | PROGRAM identifier LPAREN identifier_list RPAREN
        ;

identifier_list : identifier_list COMMA identifier
        | identifier
        ;

block : label_declaration_part
        constant_definition_part
        type_definition_part
        variable_declaration_part
        procedure_and_function_declaration_part
        statement_part
        ;

module : constant_definition_part
        type_definition_part
        variable_declaration_part
        procedure_and_function_declaration_part
        ;

label_declaration_part : LABEL label_list semicolon
        |
        ;

label_list : label_list comma label
        | label
        ;

label : DIGSEQ
        ;

constant_definition_part : CONST constant_list
        |
        ;

constant_list : constant_list constant_definition
        | constant_definition
        ;

constant_definition : identifier EQUAL cexpression semicolon
        ;

/*constant : cexpression ;              /* good stuff! */

cexpression : csimple_expression
        | csimple_expression relop csimple_expression
        ;

csimple_expression : cterm
        | csimple_expression addop cterm
        ;

cterm : cfactor
        | cterm mulop cfactor
        ;

cfactor : sign cfactor
        | cexponentiation
        ;

cexponentiation : cprimary
        | cprimary STARSTAR cexponentiation
        ;

cprimary : identifier
        | LPAREN cexpression RPAREN
        | unsigned_constant
        | NOT cprimary
        ;

constant : non_string
        | sign non_string
        | CHARACTER_STRING
        ;

sign : PLUS
        | MINUS
        ;

non_string : DIGSEQ
        | identifier
        | REALNUMBER
        ;

type_definition_part : TYPE type_definition_list
        |
        ;

type_definition_list : type_definition_list type_definition
        | type_definition
        ;

type_definition : identifier EQUAL type_denoter semicolon
        ;

type_denoter : identifier
        | new_type
        ;

new_type : new_ordinal_type
        | new_structured_type
        | new_pointer_type
        ;

new_ordinal_type : enumerated_type
        | subrange_type
        ;

enumerated_type : LPAREN identifier_list RPAREN
        ;

subrange_type : constant DOTDOT constant
        ;

new_structured_type : structured_type
        | PACKED structured_type
        ;

structured_type : array_type
        | record_type
        | set_type
        | file_type
        ;

array_type : ARRAY LBRAC index_list RBRAC OF component_type
        ;

index_list : index_list comma index_type
        | index_type
        ;

index_type : ordinal_type ;

ordinal_type : new_ordinal_type
        | identifier
        ;

component_type : type_denoter ;

record_type : RECORD record_section_list END
        | RECORD record_section_list semicolon variant_part END
        | RECORD variant_part END
        ;

record_section_list : record_section_list semicolon record_section
        | record_section
        ;

record_section : identifier_list COLON type_denoter
        ;

variant_part : CASE variant_selector OF variant_list semicolon
        | CASE variant_selector OF variant_list
        |
        ;

variant_selector : tag_field COLON tag_type
        | tag_type
        ;

variant_list : variant_list semicolon variant
        | variant
        ;

variant : case_constant_list COLON LPAREN record_section_list RPAREN
        | case_constant_list COLON LPAREN record_section_list semicolon
                variant_part RPAREN
        | case_constant_list COLON LPAREN variant_part RPAREN
        ;

case_constant_list : case_constant_list comma case_constant
        | case_constant
        ;

case_constant : constant
        | constant DOTDOT constant
        ;

tag_field : identifier ;

tag_type : identifier ;

set_type : SET OF base_type
        ;

base_type : ordinal_type ;

file_type : PFILE OF component_type
        ;

new_pointer_type : UPARROW domain_type
        ;

domain_type : identifier ;

variable_declaration_part : VAR variable_declaration_list semicolon
        |
        ;

variable_declaration_list :
          variable_declaration_list semicolon variable_declaration
        | variable_declaration
        ;

variable_declaration : identifier_list COLON type_denoter
        ;

procedure_and_function_declaration_part :
          proc_or_func_declaration_list semicolon
        |
        ;

proc_or_func_declaration_list :
          proc_or_func_declaration_list semicolon proc_or_func_declaration
        | proc_or_func_declaration
        ;

proc_or_func_declaration : procedure_declaration
        | function_declaration
        ;

procedure_declaration : procedure_heading semicolon directive
        | procedure_heading semicolon procedure_block
        ;

procedure_heading : procedure_identification
        | procedure_identification formal_parameter_list
        ;

directive : FORWARD
        | EXTERNAL
        ;

formal_parameter_list : LPAREN formal_parameter_section_list RPAREN ;

formal_parameter_section_list : 
          formal_parameter_section_list semicolon formal_parameter_section
        | formal_parameter_section
        ;

formal_parameter_section : value_parameter_specification
        | variable_parameter_specification
        | procedural_parameter_specification
        | functional_parameter_specification
        ;

value_parameter_specification : identifier_list COLON identifier
        ;

variable_parameter_specification : VAR identifier_list COLON identifier
        ;

procedural_parameter_specification : procedure_heading ;

functional_parameter_specification : function_heading ;

procedure_identification : PROCEDURE identifier ;

procedure_block : block ;

function_declaration : function_heading semicolon directive
        | function_identification semicolon function_block
        | function_heading semicolon function_block
        ;

function_heading : FUNCTION identifier COLON result_type
        | FUNCTION identifier formal_parameter_list COLON result_type
        ;

result_type : identifier ;

function_identification : FUNCTION identifier ;

function_block : block ;

statement_part : compound_statement ;

compound_statement : PBEGIN statement_sequence END ;

statement_sequence : statement_sequence semicolon statement
        | statement
        ;

statement : open_statement
        | closed_statement
        ;

open_statement : label COLON non_labeled_open_statement
        | non_labeled_open_statement
        ;

closed_statement : label COLON non_labeled_closed_statement
        | non_labeled_closed_statement
        ;

non_labeled_closed_statement : assignment_statement
        | procedure_statement
        | goto_statement
        | compound_statement
        | case_statement
        | repeat_statement
        | closed_with_statement
        | closed_if_statement
        | closed_while_statement
        | closed_for_statement
        |
        ;

non_labeled_open_statement : open_with_statement
        | open_if_statement
        | open_while_statement
        | open_for_statement
        ;

repeat_statement : REPEAT statement_sequence UNTIL boolean_expression
        ;

open_while_statement : WHILE boolean_expression DO open_statement
        ;

closed_while_statement : WHILE boolean_expression DO closed_statement
        ;

open_for_statement : FOR control_variable ASSIGNMENT initial_value direction
                        final_value DO open_statement
        ;

closed_for_statement : FOR control_variable ASSIGNMENT initial_value direction
                        final_value DO closed_statement
        ;

open_with_statement : WITH record_variable_list DO open_statement
        ;

closed_with_statement : WITH record_variable_list DO closed_statement
        ;

open_if_statement : IF boolean_expression THEN statement
        | IF boolean_expression THEN closed_statement ELSE open_statement
        ;

closed_if_statement : IF boolean_expression THEN closed_statement
                        ELSE closed_statement
        ;

assignment_statement : variable_access ASSIGNMENT expression
        ;

variable_access : identifier
        | indexed_variable
        | field_designator
        | variable_access UPARROW
        ;

indexed_variable : variable_access LBRAC index_expression_list RBRAC
        ;

index_expression_list : index_expression_list comma index_expression
        | index_expression
        ;

index_expression : expression ;

field_designator : variable_access DOT identifier
        ;

procedure_statement : identifier params
        | identifier
        ;

params : LPAREN actual_parameter_list RPAREN ;

actual_parameter_list : actual_parameter_list comma actual_parameter
        | actual_parameter
        ;

/*
 * this forces you to check all this to be sure that only write and
 * writeln use the 2nd and 3rd forms, you really can't do it easily in
 * the grammar, especially since write and writeln aren't reserved
 */
actual_parameter : expression
        | expression COLON expression
        | expression COLON expression COLON expression
        ;

goto_statement : GOTO label
        ;

case_statement : CASE case_index OF case_list_element_list END
        | CASE case_index OF case_list_element_list semicolon END
        | CASE case_index OF case_list_element_list semicolon
                        otherwisepart statement END
        | CASE case_index OF case_list_element_list semicolon
                        otherwisepart statement semicolon END
        ;

case_index : expression ;

case_list_element_list : case_list_element_list semicolon case_list_element
        | case_list_element
        ;

case_list_element : case_constant_list COLON statement
        ;

otherwisepart : OTHERWISE
        | OTHERWISE COLON
        ;

control_variable : identifier ;

initial_value : expression ;

direction : TO
        | DOWNTO
        ;

final_value : expression ;

record_variable_list : record_variable_list comma variable_access
        | variable_access
        ;

boolean_expression : expression ;

expression : simple_expression
        | simple_expression relop simple_expression
        ;

simple_expression : term
        | simple_expression addop term
        ;

term : factor
        | term mulop factor
        ;

factor : sign factor
        | exponentiation
        ;

exponentiation : primary
        | primary STARSTAR exponentiation
        ;

primary : variable_access
        | unsigned_constant
        | function_designator
        | set_constructor
        | LPAREN expression RPAREN
        | NOT primary
        ;

unsigned_constant : unsigned_number
        | CHARACTER_STRING
        | NIL
        ;

unsigned_number : unsigned_integer | unsigned_real ;

unsigned_integer : DIGSEQ
        ;

unsigned_real : REALNUMBER
        ;

/* functions with no params will be handled by plain identifier */
function_designator : identifier params
        ;

set_constructor : LBRAC member_designator_list RBRAC
        | LBRAC RBRAC
        ;

member_designator_list : member_designator_list comma member_designator
        | member_designator
        ;

member_designator : member_designator DOTDOT expression
        | expression
        ;

addop: PLUS
        | MINUS
        | OR
        ;

mulop : STAR
        | SLASH
        | DIV
        | MOD
        | AND
        ;

relop : EQUAL
        | NOTEQUAL
        | LT
        | GT
        | LE
        | GE
        | IN
        ;

identifier : IDENTIFIER
        ;

semicolon : SEMICOLON
        ;

comma : COMMA
        ;

%%

extern int line_no;
extern char *yytext;

int yyerror(s)
char *s;
{
        fprintf(stderr, "%s: at or before '%s', line %d\n", 
                        s, yytext, line_no);
}





main (void) {

    extern int init(); 

 extern FILE *yyin;
 extern int yylex(); 
 extern int yylineno;
 extern char *yytext;


   yyin = fopen("D:\\helloword.pascal", "r");

    if(yyparse()){
     printf("error"); 
    }
    else {
        printf("good"); 
    }





    fclose(yyin); 
    getchar();







    }
```

Pascal input file

```
program Hello; 
begin someErrorText1
  writeln ('Hello, world.') someErrorText2
  writeln ('Hello, world2.')
end.
```

output

[Console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gY8xe.jpg)

And you see error is in line 2 but parser show 3, and doesn't show second error.

Comment: YACC doesn't know how to recover after an error, that's something you need to specify as part of the grammar. Effectively it can scan for a token you expect to see at the end of a statement by means of the special `error` token. It has no concept of lines since your lexer eats them, but the `end` of a block, closing parenthesis or semicolon seem like reasonable candidates.

Comment: Oh, and the reason that the error is reported on the third line is simply because that's where the first unexpected token (`writeln`) lies. The parser accepts `someErrorText1` as the identifier of a `procedure_statement` or `assignment_statement` and looks for parenthesis or an operator, e.g. `someErrorText1` might have been a function with the argument list on the next line.

Comment: @doynax - thanks for response. So do you have any idea how to force the parser to find more than one error ?

Comment: Yes, you need to write [error-handling rules](http://dinosaur.compilertools.net/bison/bison_9.html) telling `bison` from what points it may resume parsing after a failure (with `yyerrok` in an `error` rule). It is something which needs to be done with care and knowledge of the grammar however and cannot be automated, otherwise you tend to end up with pointless error spew from countless failed recovery attempts.